# are not-Long primary keys possible?

Tags: scala, sorm

Is it possible to define not-Long primary key?

Motivation: I have a set of XML files to convert to rdb. String attributes are used as unique keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible.

[From docs](http://sorm-framework.org/Documentation.html#what_should_you_do_when_you_need_to_specify_the_id_yourself):

> **What should you do when you need to specify the id yourself?**
>
> Nothing. You shouldn’t do that. The id property is supposed to be generated and managed by db only. If you need to specify some external unique identifier, like, for instance, Amazon’s ASIN, just add an appropriate field to your entity and specify it as unique on SORM instantiation.